# Brand new to R for MBA class

Tags: r

Can someone give me any hint why I'm getting an error message here? If I run this code where it's not in gray, it runs. When I copy/paste it to the gray section, I get an error.

Again, brand new to R here, so I'm sure it's something obvious but trying to get through an assignment and stuck here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJXbk.jpg)

Comment: Welcome. Please don't post images of your code - paste it directly into the question as it makes it much easier for others to help. And read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) about how to ask a good question in R. Again, it'll help others answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess from the picture (post your code next time not a picture) is that your working directory isn't where your file is located. Use `setwd("your file path here")` to specify to R where your file of interest is located.